# Radius of Convergence for an infinit sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given the following infinite sum,

$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { x^n }{\sqrt{n+1}}  } $$

**a)** Find the radius of convergence? Find for what values of $\rho$ it is convergent and divergent?

**b)** Find the sum for $x=-1$ with an error of highest $0.01$, by using the sum of a finite sum with of a suitable number of variables.

**My Approach**

So what I have done so far is the following,

**a)** I used the ratio to determine the radius of convergence,

$$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$

$$|\frac{\frac { x^{n+1} }{\sqrt{(n+1)+1}}  }{\frac { x^n }{\sqrt{n+1}}  }|$$

$$|\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+2}} \times x|$$

As n goes towards infinity, we get the following,

$$|x|$$

Hence therefore the radius of convergence, $\rho=1$.

Now if

$x=\rho=1$, then the sum is divergent because it is not less than 1.

$x=-\rho=1$, then the sum is convergent because it is less than 1.

**(Is it correct how I have solve part a)?**

b) For this part, I am not sure even how to start. Because how am I suppose to determine a finite sum to find the sum for the error 0.01. Any hint or help will be great.

Comment: At $n=-1$, we get $\eta(1/2)-\frac1{\sqrt2}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint for (b):**

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sum^N_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\sum^\infty_{n=N+1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\left|\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\sum^N_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \right| =&\ \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+4}}+\ldots \right|\\
=&\ \left|\frac{\sqrt{N+2}-\sqrt{N+1}}{\sqrt{(N+2)(N+1)}} \right|+\left|\frac{\sqrt{N+3}-\sqrt{N+2}}{\sqrt{(N+3)(N+2)}} \right|+\ldots\\
\leq&\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{N+2}(N+1)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+3}(N+2)}+\ldots \\
\leq&\ \int^\infty_{N} \frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{x+2}} \leq \int^\infty_{N} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}. 
\end{align}

Evaluate the last integral to get a bound on the error. Then see for what $N$ you will have an error of at most $.01$.

Edit: I have used the fact that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{N+2}-\sqrt{N+1} =&\ \frac{\sqrt{N+2}+\sqrt{N+1}}{\sqrt{N+2}+\sqrt{N+1}}[\sqrt{N+2}-\sqrt{N+1}] \\
=&\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{N+2}+\sqrt{N+1}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank You. So that means I have to solve (integral)=0.01 and then solve for N, right?

Comment: @captainavenger96 exactly – you solve the integral in terms of $N$ and $\infty$ (which should disappear) and you'll be left with a function in terms of $N$ which is equal to $0.01$, which you can then solve :)

Comment: Great. Thank you once again for your help :)

Comment: its (n+1) in the square root, right? I have been trying to understand why have you written sqrt(n)?

Comment: I have used the fact that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Which follows from $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: At $n=-1$, we get $\eta(1/2)-\frac1{\sqrt2}.$  One can also use reindexing to make it $\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there for **a**.

Yes, the radius of convergence is $1$. You could also use the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, as told to me by a great mathematician by the name Don Antonio.

When $x=1$, the sum becomes

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}$$

This diverges according to the Limit Comparison Test with $\frac{1}{n^{0.5}}$.

When $x=-1$, it is

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}}$$

This converges according to the Alternating Series Test, as it a) alternates and b) is decreasing (try looking at the derivative of $f(n)=\left|{u_n}\right|$ and see if the function is increasing or decreasing!)

I don't know about **b**, sorry!

Comment: Thank You for your time and help!! :)

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could be of help. Also if you choose an answer to this question, please choose the other guy, he did most of the helping ;)

Comment: At $n=-1$, we get $\eta(1/2)-\frac1{\sqrt2}.$  Also, you could use reindexing to get $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}$, which may be easier to work with.